# Why does a small, particular change in this loop's range cause such a massive change in execution time - from 15ms to infinity?

Tags: c, arrays, performance, visual-c++, memory

I noticed some off behavior from this test. The outer loop, when modified slightly, say by adding a zero, it suddenly changes the execution time from ~15ms to an infinite amount of time. The execution times doesn't change linearly at all - at most it's 30ms if it doesn't go on forever and at its least it's zero. I set the stack size to several million for there to be enough room for the stack allocated array, so the problem is not a stack overflow being thrown. Anyway, please test this code [for visual studio 2012, with auto parallelization and vectorization on] out. Ignore the #ifdef and #pragma if you're using another compiler.

I set the stack virtual [reserve] and physical [allocated] memory to 8000000 or greater and set them to the same number. Why? I don't quiet understand why I would need to pull up or page memory from disk if I can allocate an entire gigabyte or two of physical RAM memory to the stack without running out of memory.

Anyway, here's the test code, just a bunch of time wasting loops and array calculations. It is run on release mode, optimized for speed.

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#endif

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int 
main(void)
{
  clock_t       begin , end;
  double        time_spent;
  const int      *__restrict const arr1 = (int *)_alloca(300000 * sizeof(int));
  const int      *__restrict const arr2 = (int *)_alloca(300000 * sizeof(int));
  const int      *__restrict const arr3 = (int *)_alloca(300000 * sizeof(int));
  int            *__restrict const arr4 = (int *)_alloca(300000 * sizeof(int));

  begin = clock();
  {
    register int    i;
    /*
     * Add or remove a zero from this outer loop and note the
     * peculiar change in execution time.
     */
    for (i = 0; i < 200000; ++i) {
#pragma loop(hint_parallel(3))
#pragma loop(ivdep)
      for (i = 0; i < 300000; ++i) {
        arr4[i] = arr1[i] + arr2[i] * arr3[i] - i + arr1[i] + arr2[i] * arr3[i] - i - arr1[i] + arr2[i] * arr3[i] - i -
          -7 * arr1[i] + arr2[i] * arr3[i] - i + arr1[i] + arr2[i] * arr3[i] - i - arr1[i] + arr2[i] * arr3[i] +
          arr1[i] + arr2[i] * arr3[i] - i + arr1[i] + arr2[i] * arr3[i] - i - arr1[i] + arr2[i] * arr3[i];
      }
      arr4[2] = arr1[7] * arr4[888] - i;
      arr4[20000] += arr3[20000] - arr2[777] * i;
    }
  }
  end = clock();
  time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

  printf("arr[4] as integer %i \n", arr4[2]);
  printf("Test1: time as a floating point type is %f \n", time_spent);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are using the same loop variable, `i`, in both loops. This means that after the innermost loop has completed its iterations, `i` equals 300000, and so the outermost loop breaks after its *first* iteration. However, if you increase the limit in the outermost loop, the innermost loop will get to run again, restarting `i` and leaving it at 300000 again. Use `for (int j = 0; j < 200000; ++j)` in the outermost loop instead.

Comment: Thank you for catching that. That perfectly explains who increasing the outer loop above 300000 caused such a huge change in execution time.

Comment: @John-MichaelReed Please accept Aasmund's answer if it resolved your problem.